# Can you recommend some books on elliptic function?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I plan to study elliptic function.  Can you recommend  some  books? What is the relationship between elliptic function and elliptic curve？Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [this paper](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/doc/ellipses_not_ecs.pdf). It gives a brief history of elliptic curves including the answer to your second question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

McKean and Moll have written the nice book *[Elliptic Curves: Function Theory, Geometry, Arithmetic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521658179)* that cleanly illustrates the connection between elliptic curves and elliptic/modular functions. If you haven't seen the book already, you should.

As for elliptic functions proper, my suggested books tend to be a bit on the old side, so pardon me if I don't know the newer treatments. Anyway, I quite liked Lawden's *[Elliptic Functions and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387969659)* and Akhiezer's *[Elements of the Theory of Elliptic Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821886770)*. An oldie but goodie is Greenhill's classic, *[The Applications of Elliptic Functions](http://archive.org/details/applicationsofel00greeuoft)*; the notation is a bit antiquated, but I have yet to see another book that has a wide discussion of the applications of elliptic functions to physical problems.

> At one time... every young mathematician was familiar with $\mathrm{sn}\,u$, $\mathrm{cn}\,u$, and $\mathrm{dn}\,u$, and algebraic identities between these functions figured in every examination.

– E.H. Neville

---

Finally, I would be remiss if I did not mention the venerable Abramowitz and Stegun, and the successor work, the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/). The chapters on the Jacobi and Weierstrass elliptic functions give a nice overview of the most useful identities, and also point to other fine work on the subject.

Comment: It's hard to choose. all answers are good

Comment: I bought a copy of McKean and Moll based on this recommendation, and although it seems like a fine book, I would caution others that it is a graduate textbook and not at all easy to read. My background is that I have an undergraduate degree in math and a graduate degree in physics, and I reviewed my complex analysis before starting in on McKean and Moll. The book is written in a style that clearly assumes the reader is taking a graduate course in the subject, with the willingness to commit the implied amount of time. It's hard to find the main thread of the story they want to tell.

Answer (score 8):

First of all

- ever-modern  [Course of modern analysis](http://lib.org.by/info/M_Mathematics/MC_Calculus/MCat_Advanced%20calculus/Whittaker%20E.T.,%20Watson%20G.N.%20A%20course%20of%20modern%20analysis%20%284ed.,%20CUP,%201927%29%28T%29%28ISBN%200521588073%29%28612s%29.djvu) by Whittaker-Watson.

For a more introductory style, I highly recommend

- V. Prasolov, Y. Solovyev [Elliptic Functions and Elliptic Integrals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821805878).

The relation between elliptic curves and elliptic functions can be sketched as follows. Elliptic curve is topologically a torus which can be realized by cutting a parallelogram in $\mathbb{C}$ and identifying its opposite edges. On the other hand, it can be realized  in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ by an algebraic equation of the form
$$y^2=x^3+ax+b.$$
Elliptic functions provide a map between the two pictures, which is also called uniformization. Essentially, $x,y$ are given by some elementary elliptic functions of $z$ (complex coordinate on the parallelogram).

Compare this with a more familiar example: trigonometric functions $\sin$, $\cos$ provide a uniformization of the circle, which can be defined either via an algebraic equation or in a parametric form:
$$x^2+y^2=1\quad \begin{array}{c}\sin,\cos\\ \Longleftrightarrow \\ \;\end{array}\quad \begin{cases}x=\cos t,\\ y=\sin t,\\ t\in[0,2\pi].\end{cases}$$

Comment: I've forgotten to mention Prasolov/Solovyev; indeed, very nice!

Comment: The link for Prasolov is broken. A link that works is https://www.amazon.com/Functions-Integrals-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821805878/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

Answer (score 6):

There is a classical 3 volume series by [C.L. Siegel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471608440). It is well-written, though the perspective is a little bit outdated. I guess (no book at hand) you can find treatments by Serge Lang in the GTM series as well. I am not sure if Stein's book on complex analysis studied this topic.